# What's the use of /256 and %256 in it and how is the address divided into hi and lo bits?

Tags: python, microcontroller

This is a code snippet from `lib_robotis` and the value `n` is the angle that we are inputting(to rotate the dimexel motor).

According to the architecture of the chip within the motor, we require to give the lower bit (identified by `lo`) of the goal position into the address 0x1e and the higher bit (identified by `hi`) of the goal position into the address 0x1f.

```
def move_to_encoder(self,n);
    n=min(max(n,0),self.settings['max_encoder'])
    hi,lo=n/256, n%256
    return self.write_address(0x1e, [hi,lo])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n is a number in the range 0 <= n < 256*256. It takes two bytes to express that number since one byte can encode a value from 0 to 255.

`hi,lo=n/256, n%256`

is the same as

```
hi = n / 256
lo = n % 256
```

`/` is the division operator and `%` is the remainder operator, so the above code says to divide `n` by 256 and store the quotient in `hi` and the remainder in `lo`. Each of `hi` and `lo` will be in the range 0 to 255, so they will each fit into one byte. And n == (256 * hi) + lo, so no information has been lost & the motor controller has all the information it needs to perform the desired operation.

I assume that the code in your post was written for Python 2; it won't work properly on Python 3. You should replace the `n / 256` by `n // 256` to make the code work on all versions of Python.

FWIW, there are various better ways to break a number up into high and low bytes. One uses the built-in [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) function:

`hi, lo = divmod(n, 256)`

Answer (score 2):

First of all you're talking about higher/lower *bytes*, not *bits*.

Dividing by 256 is the same as shifting rightwards 8 times, so that will basically yield the high byte. Taking the remainder of the division by 256 (through the *modulo operator* '%') effectively extracts the lower byte, since the result will be < 256 by definition.

Answer (score 2):

> we require to give the lower bit (identified by lo) of the goal position into the address 0x1e

256 is 2<sup>8</sup>, so dividing by 256 meaning *rightshifting* by 8 bits, giving you the high *byte*.

Take for example a 16-bits number:

```
1100101100101101
↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

dividing it by 256 is rightshifting by 8 bits, will give you:

```
0000000011001011
        ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

The *remainder* of the division by 256 gives you the lower *byte*.

Comment: Maybe we should merge our answers. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring your answer is well detailed, I like it and upvoted :) very nice explanation.

Comment: Ditto. :)  I didn't want to get too technical in case the OP didn't know much about binary; besides, I was racing against the clock...

Answer (score 1):

Think of bits like they are the "digits" in the binary notation. If you need to take, say, 2 rightmost digits of the number 256, you simply write 256%100, where 100 is 10^2. Likewise, to take 8 rightmost "binary digits", i.e. bits, you have to divide the number by 2^8, i.e. 256.